# How to require an enum be defined in Swift Protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

Is it possible to have a Protocol require that an enum be defined?

```
//trying to do this
protocol JSONEncodable {
    enum PropertyName // Type not allowed here
    func valueForProperty(propertyName:PropertyName) -> Any
}

//which would be implemented like this
struct Person : JSONEncodable {
    var firstName : String
    var lastName : String

    enum PropertyName {
        case FirstName
        case LastName
        func allValues() {
            return [Person.PropertyName.FirstName, Person.PropertyName.LastName]
        }
        func stringValue() {
            return "\(self)"
        }
    }
    func valueForProperty(propertyName:PropertyName) -> Any {
        switch propertyName {

        case .FirstName:
            return firstName

        case .LastName:
            return lastName
        }
    }
}

//so that I could do something like this
extension JSONEncodable {

    func JSONObject() -> [String:AnyObject] {
        var dictionary = [String:AnyObject]()
        for propertyName in PropertyName.allValues {
            let value = valueForProperty(propertyName)

            if let valueObject = value as? AnyObject {
                dictionary[propertyName.stringValue()] = valueObject

            }else if let valueObject = value as? JSONEncodable {
                dictionary[propertyName.stringValue()] = valueObject.JSONObject()
            }

        }
        return dictionary
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: Why would you want this? What're you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Protocols can have `associatedtypes` which would just need to be adhered to in any subclass:

```
enum MyEnum: String {
    case foo
    case bar
}

protocol RequiresEnum {
    associatedtype SomeEnumType: RawRepresentable where SomeEnumType.RawValue: StringProtocol

    func doSomethingWithEnum(someEnumType: SomeEnumType)
}

class MyRequiresEnum: RequiresEnum {
    typealias SomeEnumType = MyEnum

    func doSomethingWithEnum(someEnumType: SomeEnumType) {
        switch someEnumType {
        case .foo:
            print("foo")
        case .bar:
            print("bar")
        }
    }
}

let mre = MyRequiresEnum()
mre.doSomethingWithEnum(someEnumType: .bar)
```

**Edit:** The `associatedtype` **must** be adhered to

Comment: Neat, though there's nothing forcing SomeEnumType to actually be an Enum type. Works though.

Comment: My own solution to the problem is similar to this but this approach exposes the enum's accessibility to those controllers not even adopting the protocol. I am wondering how can the enum be scoped only to the adopting protocol. But since enum is not allowed inside Protocol, is there another way to represent the cases without using enum?

Answer (score 22):

I think you can do it with an `associatedtype` that adheres to `RawRepresentable`

Here's an example:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    associatedtype SomeType: RawRepresentable
}
```

If you need to specify the type of `RawRepresentable` like `String` for example, you can do that:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    associatedtype SomeType: RawRepresentable where SomeType.RawValue: StringProtocol
}
```

Now you'll have a compiler error if you try to implement the protocol with anything else than an `enum` that has `String` as `RawRepresentable`.
I hope it helps.